# Cannot copy or convert flat file data for column

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I am facing issue with ssis package while converting Datetime field from oledb source to flatfile file. this i am not facing every time its happening some times. please help me on this. i have data type for DB_Timestamp for the column in destination DT_STR (50).

> Executed as user: NA\X16871. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 12.0.5000.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  3:30:08 PM  Error: 2017-11-16 16:40:37.45     Code: 0xC0202053     Source: DFT - Error Reports FF DST Load Error Report [2]     Description: Cannot write to the data file.  End Error  Error: 2017-11-16 16:40:37.45     Code: 0xC02020A0     Source: DFT - Error Reports FF DST Load Error Report [2]     Description: Cannot copy or convert flat file data for column "OPEN_SINCE".  End Error  Error: 2017-11-16 16:40:37.45     Code: 0xC0047022     Source: DFT - Error Reports SSIS.Pipeline     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "FF DST Load Error Report" (2) failed with error code 0xC02020A0 while processing input "Flat File Destination Input" (6). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error  Error: 2017-11-16 16:40:43.48     Code: 0xC0209017     Source: DFT - Error Reports OLE DB Source [35]     Description: Setting the end of rowset for the buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.  End Error  Error: 2017-11-16 16:40:43.48     Code: 0xC0047038     Source: DFT - Error Reports SSIS.Pipeline     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on OLE DB Source returned error code 0xC0209017.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error  Error: 2017-11-16 16:40:43.48     Code: 0xC0202053     Source: DFT - Error Reports FF DST Load Error Report [2]     Description: Cannot write to the data file.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  3:30:08 PM  Finished: 4:40:43 PM  Elapsed:  4234.5 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Comment: What is the "oledb" source?

Comment: oledb source is to get data from sqlserver using query

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d0753395-2994-4bd1-948e-0757e5557b0f/flat-file-error?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Did u checked run time on flatfile connection manager ?

Comment: B House, i did not get you...

Comment: is the package on 32 bit runtime or 64 bit

Comment: its not required because not failing all the time.....

Comment: I understand, i used to have same kind of issue a while ago, i have changed run time, can not explain why this makes difference. I would say use a data conversion task and test

Answer (score 1):

Conversion error occurs sometimes, I would rather look at source component. Right click on `OLEDB` source and click on Advance editor and look for Input/Output properties. Expand Output columns and check for data type. Change it to `db_timestamp`, sometimes it fails and succeeds if data type is `dt_str`.

[image: Output Properties]

Comment: I have checked data type as well, source data type is DT_DBTIMESTAMP and for destination CSV file it is DT_STR data type

Comment: Change it ti Dt_str in source

Comment: if i am creating a new package i can do that but i am doing debugging on existing package which was running successfully before and failed recently with the above error and even no changes implemented on the package.

Comment: I would say, you should make changes to existing package and redeploy it. Source destination mismatch can get errors sometimes ( most times dt_str can be compatible with db_timestamp), so as u knew this mapping, changes are necessary

Comment: are you sure sometimes it happens.....or is there any reason behind that like messing up data from two columns into single for delimited file.

Comment: It could be definitely source data, are u concating or combining 2 columns ?

Comment: no i am not combining, actually its datetime field in a source table are you sure will it have data issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is a Data conversion issue, Your flat file has DT_STR but your source field has the Type DT_DBTIMESTAMP. you should either convert your source or your destination field so that both have the same Datatype. Although I'm not sure how the package was running prior to this if there were not changes made while debugging.

Comment: Ranjit dt_dbtimestamp is compatible to dt_str that's why its running fine. Even now also running fine not sure again when it throw an error.